# Как отправлять данные с докера во внешний мир?

Tags: docker

запускаю docker контейнер, перехожу в localhost и вместо интерфейса приложения вижу нечто такое: **Сайт localhost не отправил данные.**

запуск контейнера произвожу таким образом: `docker run -d -p 5173:5173 --name test test`

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.17
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm i
EXPOSE 5173
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

В гугле и книгах не смог найти достаточно информации на этот счет, чтобы решить проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оказывается, что достаточно было добавить в файл конфигурации vite:

```
  server: {
    host: true,
  }
```

и все заработало.